# How to disable translate popup chrome

Tags: docker-compose, automated-tests, appium, codeception

I'm using docker, appium, codeception for test real devices (Mi, Nexus 5X) in chrome.

When I start my test (new browser) I see popup of translate this site. I dunno how to hide or disable this. 
popup of translate this site.

P.S. : --disable-translate not working now.